# Constant Lock Wait Timeout with MySQL InnoDB table

Tags: mysql, locking, innodb, wait

I'm having horrible issues with lock wait timeouts with a MySQL InnoDB table created like so:

```
CREATE TABLE `TableX` (
  `colID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `colFK` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `colX` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `colX` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `colX` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `colX` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `colX` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `colX` binary(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0',
  `colX` int(10) unsigned zerofill NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000000000',
  `colX` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `colX` int(10) unsigned zerofill NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000000000',
  `colX` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`colFK`),
  UNIQUE KEY `colID` (`colID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

The error is as follows: "[Err] 1205 - Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction"

This table never has more than 120 records in it but it gets hit hard with SELECT, UPDATE and DELETE statements. Very basic queries mostly filtering on the tableID but a join in some select statements to other tables with less than 2,000 records. I've tested all of the select queries and they take less than 100-200 ms to execute.

InnoDB Status returns the following when the issue is happening:

```
---TRANSACTION 2605217, ACTIVE 1 sec inserting
 mysql tables in use 1, locked 1
 LOCK WAIT 2 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 1 row lock(s)
 MySQL thread id 11826, OS thread handle 4104, query id 1940531 xxxx xxxxx xxxx update
 INSERT INTO TableX(cols) VALUES(values)
 ------- TRX HAS BEEN WAITING 1 SEC FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
 RECORD LOCKS space id 227 page no 3 n bits 168 index PRIMARY of table `TableX` trx id 2605217 lock mode S locks rec but not gap waiting
 Record lock, heap no 97 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 14; compact format; info bits 32
```

The general query log shows 4 selects and an insert happening within a second. The INSERT is the transaction failing with the lock wait timeout. So my question is, what can I do about this? I've tried reconfiguring the server, reinstalling MySQL, changing the transaction level..

I apologize if the formatting is off I couldn't get the create table into a code block. Feel free to edit my post or ask for any more information that is required. Thanks!

Edit: Adding general query log +-wait timeout

```
2017-05-02T02:06:26.443095Z 12195 Query SELECT SQL_BUFFER_RESULT * FROM TableX LEFT JOIN TableY USING (ColA) LEFT JOIN TableA USING (ColA) LEFT JOIN TableZ USING (ColA) LEFT JOIN TableH USING (ColA) LEFT JOIN TableI USING(ColA) WHERE UnindexedCol IS NOT NULL AND UnindexedColB <= 0  ORDER BY UnindexedCol ASC
2017-05-02T02:06:26.708769Z 11829 Query SELECT * FROM TableX LEFT JOIN TableA ON TableX.ColA = TableA.ColA WHERE UnindexedCol = 'text' LIMIT 1
2017-05-02T02:06:27.021306Z 11826 Query SELECT * FROM TableX WHERE IDColA = 1000
2017-05-02T02:06:27.068185Z 11826 Query INSERT INTO TableX(cols) VALUES(values)
2017-05-02T02:06:27.224393Z 11829 Query SELECT colList, MIN(ColA) FROM TableX JOIN TableY USING (ColA) WHERE IF (IDColE <> 0, IDColE = (SELECT MAX(IDColE) FROM TableY WHERE IDColF = 22073), IDColF = 22073) GROUP BY UnIndexedColS, UnIndexedColT
2017-05-02T02:06:27.224393Z  1697 Query Show engine innodb status
2017-05-02T02:06:27.224393Z  1696 Query SELECT st.* FROM performance_schema.events_statements_current st JOIN performance_schema.threads thr ON thr.thread_id = st.thread_id WHERE thr.processlist_id = 1697
2017-05-02T02:06:27.224393Z  1696 Query SELECT st.* FROM performance_schema.events_stages_history_long st WHERE st.nesting_event_id = 211
2017-05-02T02:06:27.224393Z  1696 Query SELECT st.* FROM performance_schema.events_waits_history_long st WHERE st.nesting_event_id = 211
2017-05-02T02:06:28.224501Z 11829 Query SELECT ColList FROM TableX WHERE UnIndexedCol = 2 OR UnIndexedCol = 2 GROUP BY ColList
```

Here is the C++ code being used to call the queries:

```
*  Executes a query.                                                    *

int32 Sql_Query(Sql_t* self, const char* query, ...)
{
    int32 res;
    va_list args;

    va_start(args, query);
    res = Sql_QueryV(self, query, args);
    va_end(args);

    return res;
}

*  Executes a query.                                                    *

int32 Sql_QueryV(Sql_t* self, const char* query, va_list args)
{
    if( self == NULL )
        return SQL_ERROR;

    Sql_FreeResult(self);
    StringBuf_Clear(&self->buf);
    StringBuf_Vprintf(&self->buf, query, args);
    if( mysql_real_query(&self->handle, StringBuf_Value(&self->buf), (uint32)StringBuf_Length(&self->buf)) )
    {
        ShowSQL("DB error - %s\n", mysql_error(&self->handle));
        ShowSQL("Query: %s\n", StringBuf_Value(&self->buf));
        return SQL_ERROR;
    }
    self->result = mysql_store_result(&self->handle);
    if( mysql_errno(&self->handle) != 0 )
    {
        ShowSQL("DB error - %s\n", mysql_error(&self->handle));
        ShowSQL("Query: %s\n", StringBuf_Value(&self->buf));
        return SQL_ERROR;
    }
    return SQL_SUCCESS;
}

int     STDCALL mysql_real_query(MYSQL *mysql, const char *q,
                    unsigned int length);

MYSQL_RES * STDCALL mysql_store_result(MYSQL *mysql);
```

Comment: I removed the 'deadlock' tag. A lock wait is not a deadlock.

Comment: Do you really need 2 unique keys?  That probably doubles the number of locks involved.

Comment: Let's see the concurrent `SELECTs`.

Comment: Added the query log with all selects hitting the table within +- wait timeout. I noticed I have a filter on <= where I could have used = so I've changed that. I could remove the Primary Key on the FK I don't think it's needed since I should be managing it in the code...

Answer (score 4):

The best thing you can do about it is **finish your transactions promptly.**

Lock duration has nothing to do with how fast the query executes. It's about how long the lock remains held. The lock is held until the transaction commits or rolls back.

For example, if session 1 does this following:

```
START TRANSACTION;
UPDATE TableX SET colX = 1234 WHERE colID >= 5678;
```

this transaction will hold locks on all rows with colID > 5678, *including the gap at the end*. This is usually what blocks inserts.

See [InnoDB Locking: Gap Locks](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-locking.html#innodb-gap-locks) to understand some about gap locks.

You can avoid most gap locks by setting transaction isolation level to `READ COMMITTED` but make sure this is okay for what your application needs in terms of logic.

You can also solve this by resolving the transaction before your code does anything that's going to take an unbounded amount of time. What I mean by this is (pseudocode):

```
start transaction;
do some sql query that acquires locks;
post data to a web service that takes 500ms to respond;
commit;
```

The above will hold the lock unnecessarily for half a second. If you have a dozen of these running concurrently, the last one will wait for >6 seconds, because it has to wait for all those that got in line before it. If you have more, they'll wait longer.

It'd be better to do this:

```
start transaction;
do some sql query that acquires locks;
commit;
post data to a web service that takes 500ms to respond;
```

---

Re your comments.

Every statement uses a transaction. If you don't control transactions start and finish explicitly, you might be using *autocommit* where each statement implicitly starts a transaction and commits the transaction as soon as the statement is done executing. So perhaps your SQL statements are taking too long.

Another idea: your SQL queries are using a search against an unindexed column. I see in your example table you have colID as the PK, and colFK as a foreign key (which is always indexed). If your search is for any other column, it must do a table-scan to do the search, and that means it locks *every* row it examines. If you use an index to help your searches, it will also minimize the number of rows it needs to lock, which will help concurrent updates a lot.

---

Re your update with queries and C++ code.

INSERT causes locks but they should be small in scope, and brief. We see in your SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS that your INSERT is waiting for access to the table's primary key. So some other thread must have it locked.

When you see a locking problem, you can query the INFORMATION_SCHEMA.INNODB_LOCK_WAITS table to see which transactions are waiting and which transaction is making them wait (i.e. blocking). This only works if you query while the lock-wait is still waiting. See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-lock-waits-table.html

Most of your queries are SELECT statements, and they're non-locking SELECTs. These types of queries don't wait for locks when you use InnoDB tables, if you're just doing INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE concurrently. Nor do they block other threads.

SELECT can wait for (or block) a metadata lock if you are doing ALTER TABLE, or if you're using explicit [LOCK TABLES](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/lock-tables.html) statements. But you haven't mentioned that you're doing either of these.

SELECT has options to do [locking reads](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-locking-reads.html), but you don't show any of these options in the SELECT statements you show.

Also double-check the value of your config options [innodb_lock_wait_timeout](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_lock_wait_timeout) (follow the link to read more about this). The default is 50 seconds, but if someone has set this to a very small value like 0 it could cause spurious timeouts.

```
mysql> SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLE LIKE 'innodb_lock_wait_timeout';
```

Comment: Hi Bill, thanks for replying and helping with the tags! I am not specifying  START/COMMIT transactions on my queries [Just dirty UPDATE/INSERTS] (which are coming from multiple C++ apps).  I've looked through my SQL wrapper and don't see anything transaction related either.  The database level 'tx_isolation' variable is set to 'REPEATABLE-READ' so I will change it to  'READ-COMMITTED' and will report back. Also My UPDATE statements are being run with equal statements, not against ranges if that makes a difference?

Comment: What I meant be "equals statements" was = sign filters. for instance:
UPDATE TableX SET ColX = value WHERE ColID = xxx

Comment: I hope you are not using `autocommit=0`.

Comment: autocommit is on, I will try creating indexes on the columns filtered on and if that doesn't help I will post my C++ code. Thank you for your suggestions!

Comment: I've added the C++ code because I'm still having issues. Started using innotop to try and diagnose but no luck so far. If anything else is needed let me know. Also if its not possible to figure this out do you know of a good MSSQL C++ library? Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the reply Bill, I'm going to split my applications out so a lock wait doesn't cause the entire system to crash and increase the lock wait timeout as you suggest. Hopefully after a few more days of debugging I can mark this as the correct answer!